# Trying to remove a node from a linked list & not understanding the error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures, rspec, linked-list

I am trying to build a program that will build and manipulate a doubly linked list in Ruby.

So far I have been able to satisfy the test that tell me i've built the list but am struggling to get my `delete` method working.

right now my Rspec test keeps telling me:

```
Failure/Error: llist.delete(n3)
          NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `current' for #<LinkedList:0x007f85a49ae9b8>
       Did you mean?  current
```

even though I'm pretty sure i am defining the method

this is my `linkedlist.rb` file

```
require_relative 'node'

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head
  attr_accessor :tail
  bob = []
  current = nil 
  # This method creates a new `Node` using `data`, and inserts it at the end of the list.
   def add_to_tail(node)
    if(@next)
       @tail.next = node
    else
      @tail= node
    end
  end
# This method removes `node` from the list and must keep the rest of the list intact.
  def delete(node)
    current.next =@head
    if current.node = node
      @head =current.next
    else
      while (current.next != nil)&&(current.next.node != val)
        current = current.next
      end
      unless current.next == nil
        current.next =current.next.next
      end
    end

  end
```

this is the companion file that sets the `Node` class

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :next
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
    #@next = nil
  end
end
```

and these are the Rspec tests I am trying to pass

```
include RSpec

require_relative 'node'
require_relative 'linked_list'

RSpec.describe LinkedList, type: Class do
  let(:n1) { Node.new("Rob") }
  let(:n2) { Node.new("Ben") }
  let(:n3) { Node.new("Mike") }
  let(:llist) { LinkedList.new }

  describe "#add_to_tail" do
    it "adds a Node to the tail" do
      llist.add_to_tail(n1)
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n1
      llist.add_to_tail(n2)
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n2
    end
  end
  describe "#delete" do
    before do
      llist.add_to_tail(n1)
      llist.add_to_tail(n2)
      llist.add_to_tail(n3)

it "removes the correct node of a list properly" do
      llist.delete(n1)
      expect(llist.head).to eq n2
      llist.delete(n3)
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n2
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

you are defining current and bob in the class scope, however in ruby class scope variables are set with a double @@. But this will cause problems when using multiple linked lists so you don`t want to be using class variables in this case. So the best way forward would be to set an @current and @bob instance variable for your LinkedList instance. I would suggest to do the following:

change current and bob to this:

```
attr_accessor :current
attr_accessor :bob
```

what `attr_accessor` does, is creates the @current instance variable, and also defines two methods for you, a getter `current` and a setter `current=`.

the next step to set them to nil and an array, is to use the initialize method, add this to your `LinkedList` class:

```
def initialize(*args)
  @current = nil
  @bob = []
end
```

although once the `@current` instance is created, it will already be set to `nil`, so the first line in the initialize is actually redundant, I just added it for display purposes to make it easier to see what is happening compared with your current code.

Comment: Class-level instance variables are prefixed with `@@`, but using those can be problematic. It's better to use class instance variables, those defined in the class scope, if that's necessary.

Comment: indeed, hence I recommend the use of instance variables, but Class-level instance variables and class variables are different, Class variables are set with @@, Class-level instance variables are set with a single @, but defined through the meta-class with something like `class << self; attr_accessor :current; end`, which split the variable for inherited classes, but instances of the same class will still be problematic. And instance variables with the stadard @. I know I am being a bit picky but, just wanted to make the point that Class, Class-leve instancel, and instance vars are different.

Comment: Explained quite well here: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/